# getting setstate to cause a rerender every time in a useEffect block

Tags: reactjs

I've created this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usemachine-typescript-problems-m3480?file=/src/components/FormContainer/index.tsx:0-2268) example and here is the code:

```js
import React, { ReactNode, useState } from "react";
import { Formik, FormikConfig, FormikProps, Form, FormikErrors } from "formik";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { scrollToValidationError } from "./scrollToValidationError";

// const isEmpty = (a: unknown): boolean =>
//   typeof a === "object" && Object.keys(a).length > 0;

export type FormContainerProps<V> = {
  render({
    values,
    errors,
    invalid,
    submitCount,
    isSubmitting
  }: {
    values: V;
    invalid: boolean;
    errors: FormikErrors<V>;
    submitCount: number;
    isSubmitting: boolean;
  }): ReactNode;
  additionalContent?: ReactNode;
  nextButtonText?: string;
} & Pick<FormikConfig<V>, "initialValues" | "validate"> &
  Partial<Pick<FormikConfig<V>, "onSubmit">>;

export const FormContainer = function FormContainer<V>({
  initialValues,
  additionalContent,
  validate,
  render,
  ...rest
}: FormContainerProps<V>) {
  const [hasValidationError, setHasValidationError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasValidationError) {
      return;
    }

    scrollToValidationError();
  }, [hasValidationError]);

  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validate={validate}
        onSubmit={async (values, { validateForm }) => {}}
      >
        {({
          isSubmitting,
          submitCount,
          isValid,
          errors,
          values
        }: FormikProps<V>) => {
          const invalid = !isValid;

          if (submitCount > 0 && invalid) {
            setHasValidationError(true);
          }

          return (
            <>
              <div data-selector="validation-summary">Validation Summary</div>
              <Form>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    {render({
                      values,
                      errors,
                      isSubmitting,
                      invalid,
                      submitCount
                    })}
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Form>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
};
```

Basically I am calling `setHasValidationError(true)` which breaks the dependency watcher on useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasValidationError) {
      return;
    }

    scrollToValidationError();

    setTimeout(() => setHasValidationError(false));
  }, [hasValidationError]);
```

But if this is a form with multiple errors then I want to trigger the useEffect every time but I  don't know when to reset it to false or if there is a better way.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure either based on the code posted. Perhaps try simplifying your components. Also, useEffect always runs, useState (if I understand correctly will trigger re-render after each change).

Comment: the hasvalidationerror will stop the useffect callback running because the value does not change

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple errors? Which one of them should the use get scrolled to?

Comment: the top most one.  the scrolling all works.  i want the scrolling to happen each time they click the submit button but that won’t currently happen because the useeffect callback won’t trigger until one the dependency changes

Comment: This seems like non-standard usage for Formik. Take a look at the validation docs https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation

Comment: also see https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/146

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to achieve and which problems you have now?

Comment: I think you can set validation error to false in the cleanup function of the effect: `return () => setHasValidationError(false)` in the effect function instead of the timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to scroll to the first error field upon clicking on submit then you can do the following:

- Write a custom component (eg: FocuseabelField) that renders formik field which also handles `automatic scroll` to element and `focus` on error input
- Use [Formik's innerRef](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/1.3.0/api/field#innerref)
- Just use the formik's `isSubmitting` and `errors` to handle logic for scrolling and focussing

**FocuseabelField custom component**

```js
const FocuseabelField: any = props => {
  const elementRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  if (
    props.isSubmitting &&
    elementRef.current !== undefined &&
    props.errors.hasOwnProperty(props.name)
  ) {
    elementRef.current.scrollIntoView();
    elementRef.current.focus();
  }
  return <Field {...props} innerRef={elementRef} />;
};
```

**Usage**

```
<FocuseabelField
  errors={errors}
  isSubmitting={isSubmitting}
  name="name"
  placeholder="enter name"
  className={errors && errors.name ? "input error" : "input"}
/>
```

- I have taken your code and have commented the stuff like scrollToValidationerror.ts, dom.ts, wait.ts, useState(hasValidationError), useEffect etc.
- Simplified working copy of the code is here. I have used 2 fields to demonstrate multiple errors & auto scroll & focus to the error field:

https://codesandbox.io/s/usemachine-typescript-problems-tns0c?file=/src/components/Home/index.tsx

When the forms gets bigger it becomes complicated to manage so its good to consider outsourcing the form validation part and use libraries such as [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) and maintain a validation schema and pass it on to formik.

Have a look at the [formik docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating an Object with keys for each form field? That way you can maintain a specific form validation error for each input and use that Object in the useEffect second parameter, it will make sure it's triggered for each form error update

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question,

`useEffect` does reference check for its dependencies, so you could use `Object` instead of value. So something like this.

`const [hasValidationError, setHasValidationError] = useState({value: false});`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasValidationError.value) {
      return;
    }

    scrollToValidationError();
  }, [hasValidationError]);
```

```
setHasValidationError({value: true});
```

But in regards to Formik usage, I highly recommend you follow what @gdh pointed out.

Comment: I don't understand the need of fooling the react engine! Why do you use useEffect if you don't want/need it's functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need of effects here.

Why don't you call the method directly instead of using hooks?

You can avoid 2 re-renders by doing that, and the component can also be stateless!

```html
...

  }: FormikProps<V>) => {
    const invalid = !isValid;

    if (submitCount > 0 && invalid) {
      scrollToValidationError();
    }
          
...
```